# .htaccess only allow access to index.php and a directory

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

to redirect all my website traffic through index.php and let my php code get the request_uri and route each request accordingly.

I want to restrict access to all other files/directories except one that will contain the js files, css files, images etc.

I found that to do that I can use:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

and then have another .htaccess file inside the public directory to allow certain file types.

When I navigate to localhost/mysite/index.php it works fine since the index.php file is accessible.

But for any other url I get a 403, for example /mysite/home/ is forbidden even though I expected it to work normally.

What can I do get the expected behavior?

My full .htacces file is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php


Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

---

EDIT: The /public/.htaccess currently looks like this:

```
<Files ~ "\.(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|pdf)$">
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Can you show `/public/.htaccess` also?

Comment: @anubhava I edited the question to include that too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code in `/mysite/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteRule !^(public/|index\.php) [NC,F]
```

Comment: It works fine when I go to localhost/mysite/index.php,  but I still get a forbidden when I go to  localhost/mysite/home/. Shouldn't it be allowed since it's redirected to index.php?

Comment: I thought you want to allow only `http://example.com/public/*` and `http://example.com/index.php`. Is that not the case?

Comment: That is the case, but I also want to be able to have clean urls, so essentially the url `localhost/mysite/home/` is a request to `index.php` with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/mysite/home"`. The problem is that even though the request to localhost/mysite/home/ is supposed to be sent to `index.php`, it is forbidden by the `.htaccess`

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? In root or in `mysite` or in `/mysite/home/`. I think your requirement and your file/directory structure is not in complete sync.

Comment: the .htaccess is located in `mysite`. The index.php file is also in `mysite`. /mysite/home/ is not an actual directory, it is an example of a clean url, like `/mysite/anyUserRequest/secondUserRequestParameter/`

Comment: And is public a sub directory in `mysite` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm sorry if I didn't clarify that

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php
```

That is the .htaccess I use for my applications. In the public directory, I only place index.php and JS, CSS and images file that I need, so there is no need to filter them out. Any other file (such as uploads), are save to a folder outside of the public folder - so they are no accessible directly - only via a php script that reads them. I believe that is "best practice".

Comment: This would be my last resort, but I really want to find what is wrong with my .htaccess and make it work with my current file structure